# Java spring boot restcontroller not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote simple java spring boot application code
In the application, I have 3 class file

1. DemoApplication -- contains main method
2. Student class- POCO class contains following code

   ```
   package student;
   ```

   import java.time.LocalDate;

   public class Student {

   ```
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String email;
   private LocalDate dob;
   private int age;
   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }
   public void setId(Long id) {
       this.id = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   public String getEmail() {
       return email;
   }
   public void setEmail(String email) {
       this.email = email;
   }
   public LocalDate getDob() {
       return dob;
   }
   public void setDob(LocalDate dob) {
       this.dob = dob;
   }
   public int getAge() {
       return age;
   }
   public void setAge(int age) {
       this.age = age;
   }
   public Student(Long id, String name, String email, LocalDate dob, int age) {
       super();
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
       this.email = email;
       this.dob = dob;
       this.age = age;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", dob=" + dob + ", age=" + age + "]";
   }
   ```

   }
3. StudentController class-- controller contains following code

   package student;

   import java.time.LocalDate;
   import java.util.List;

   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

   @RestController
   @RequestMapping(path="/api/student")
   public class StudentController {

   ```
    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public List<Student> getStudents()
    {
        return List.of(
                new Student(
                        1L,
                        "Yuvraj Meshram",
                        "yuvraj.meshram@gmail.com",
                        LocalDate.of(2001, 5, 6),
                        21
                        )
                );
    }
   ```

   }

If I run the application,it started without any error on localhost:8080, but when I hit the url "localhost:8080/api/student/all" , it show me error page "WhiteLabel Error Page".

My pom.xml contains following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please help me with this guys.

Comment: What http status code do you get?

Comment: Is your `DemoApplication` in a different package than of Controller's?

If yes, Add `@ComponentScan(basePackages={student})` on top of DemoApplication class and see if it works!

Comment: Small recommendation: read about https://projectlombok.org and you won't need to write hundreds of lines of getters and setters, and some others

Comment: Thanks @vladtkachuk for suggestion. I already know about it, but want to start from basic.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a @ComponentScan on top of your DemoApplication class. It is probably a package issue.